# Is there a way to override a global variable in a closure's scope?

Tags: javascript, closures, metaprogramming, proxy-pattern

I have an API has a signature like

```
on(eventName, Handler)
```

Where API users use it like

```
on('myEvent', (safeAccessObject) => {
  safeAccessObject.doSomething();
});
```

Sometimes though, users refer to a global that I'd prefer them not to:

```
// assume window.dangerousAccessObject is defined

on('myEvent', (safeAccessObject) => {
  dangerousAccessObject.doSomethingUnintended();
});
```

**Is there a way to set `dangerousAccessObject` to `null` or even use some proxy of my own only within the closure of their handler?**

The idea is not to create a complete and secure sandbox, but rather show helpful debug messages to the API users. In this instance both the API of `on` as well as `dangerousAccessObject` are production code that user code relies on in other contexts and so it can't be removed.

Comment: But if the variable is global, do they even need a handler? Can't they just do `dangerousAccessObject.doSomethingUnintended();` wherever they like? In other words, why are you so focused on the handler?

Comment: @ASDFGerte because the *when* is important. They use it for actions that need to run following a certain event

Comment: So, using `dangerousAccessObject` generally is fine, but inside of a handler, it is not? In that case, can't you proxy `dangerousAccessObject`, and for all access check, whether a handler is currently running?

Comment: @ASDFGerte exactly. It's unfortunate, but that's the problem I have to solve :)